# App Store gifting with iTunes Affiliate link?

Tags: ios, app-store, affiliate

I know it's possible to link directly to the "Gift This App" page in the iTunes App (it does in fact open the iTunes App, not the App Store app) ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197035/gift-app-from-inside-the-app/9911273#9911273)), but I would like to know if it's possible to link to Gift This App *with* an Affiliate attached?

On app pages in the App Store on iOS 6, Apple has even removed the "Gift this App" button entirely, so I would not be able to link to the product page in the iTunes or App Store and ask users to do it through there.

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Gift this App" link is not officially supported for external use - but it does work.  When you wrap this link with your affiliate token an affiliate cookie will be stored on the users device.

You can confirm in your own testing by monitoring the network traffic on your device and look for the cookie named "a" passed in the store traffic.