# Gift Application through SKStoreProductViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, app-store

I've seen many apps which link buttons to the [SKStoreProductViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html) to download a specific app or specific music. This is how it is [built](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Making_Store_Purchases_with_the_SKStoreProductViewController_Class) and looks like:

---

[image]

---

I already know that it is possible to gift you app through a link to the appstore application like [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197035/gift-app-from-inside-the-app). **Now I want to know**: " *Is it possible to gift your app through this controller?*" I wondered because many apps use this `SKStoreProductViewController` to download specific apps through an ad or something similar.

*I would be glad if someone know if it's possible and maybe how...*

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the documentation goes - you can't do that.

Comment: Ok thank you for your awnser, I thought it could be possible in a way.

Comment: Actually the share button, which you can use to gift an app is in there, but it's only present on the iPad for some reason.

Comment: Oh, good to know thanks...could you upload those picture for me? I haven't an iPad so...thanks anyway.