# send gift from ios app

Tags: ios

I have used this code for sending gift

```
NSString *giftAppURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://buy.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZFinance.woa/wa/giftSongsWizard?gift=1&salableAdamId=APP_ID&productType=C&pricingParameter=STDQ"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:giftAppURL]];
```

but when app will redirect to appstore it tells me "This feature is no longer supported". 
Does apple change url for the request? or disable this feature?

Answer (score 2):

The URL you're attempting to use doesn't seem to be one of the ones officially supported by Apple, so it's not surprising that it has stopped working. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2337601/2234506) for more information on which URLs are endorsed by Apple.